# A simple question on limit of functions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Let $I$ be a real open interval, $t_0 \in I \, $, $\varepsilon > 0 \ $ and $ \ f,g:I \to \mathbb{R} \ $ functions of class $C^{\infty}$ such that

- For each $ \ t \in I \, $, $ \big( f(t) , g(t) \big) \neq (0,0) \, $;
- $[f(t_0)]^2 = [g(t_0)]^2 \, $, that is, $f(t_0) = \pm g(t_0) \, $;
- $t_0 - \varepsilon \in I \, $;
- $[f(t)]^2 \neq [g(t)]^2 \, $, $\forall t \in \; ]t_0 - \varepsilon , t_0[ \ $.

Let $ \ m : \; ]t_0 - \varepsilon , t_0[ \; \to \mathbb{R} \ $ be given by $$m(t) = \frac{|f(t) g'(t) - f'(t) g(t)|}{ \big| [f(t)]^2 - [g(t)]^2 \big|^{3/2}} \quad . $$

> I want to know the value of the one-sided limit $ \ \displaystyle \lim_{t \to t_0^{-}} m(t) \ $. Is it allways infinity? If it is the case, then how to prove it?

---

My efforts until now:

The first two hypothesis clearly imply $ \ f(t_0) \neq 0 \ $ and $ \ g(t_0) \neq 0 \ $.

I tried to find a counterexample. That is, some functions $f$ and $g$ that satisfies all the hypothesis and for which the limit of $m$ is not infinity, but I failed. I know that $ \ \big| [f(t)]^2 - [g(t)]^2 \big|^{3/2} \to 0 \ $ as $ \ t \to t_0^{-} \, $. So, a counterexample must have $ \ |f(t) g'(t) - f'(t) g(t)| \to 0 \ $ as $ \ t \to t_0^{-} \ $ faster than the denominator and I don't know if this is possible.

I already noticed that $$[W(f,g)](t) = \det \left( \begin{array}{cc} f(t) & g(t) \\ f'(t) & g'(t) \end{array} \right) = f(t) g'(t) - f'(t) g(t) \ $$ is the wronskian of $f$ and $g$ applied on $t$. Thus, if there exists a counterexample, it must consists of linearly independent functions $f$ and $g$, at least on the interval $ \ ]t_0 - \varepsilon , t_0[ \, $. That is, there is not $ \ c \in \mathbb{R} \ $ such that $ \ g(t) = c \cdot f(t) \, $, $\forall t \in \; ]t_0 - \varepsilon , t_0[ \ $. Also, if we choose $f$ such that $ \ f(t) > 0 \, , $ $\forall t \in \; ]t_0 - \varepsilon , t_0[ \ $, then $$f(t) g'(t) - f'(t) g(t) = [f(t)]^2 \cdot \left( \frac{f}{g} \right)'(t)$$ and by continuity $$0 = f(t_0) g'(t_0) - f'(t_0) g(t_0) = [f(t_0)]^2 \cdot \left( \frac{f}{g} \right)'(t_0) \ \ . $$ Hence $t_0$ must be an extrema of the function $\frac{f}{g} \, $.

I could not go any further than that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing Taylor expansions of the functions at the left of $t_0$?

Comment: @Oliv No. How can I do it?

Comment: You can try to write Taylor expansions of $f$, $f'$, $g$ and $g'$ at $t_0$, plug it into your definition of $m$ and see which terms remain after the simplifications. Not sure it works, but this is how I would  approach it first.

Comment: @Oliv For analytic functions, like you pointed out, the constant term of the denominator vanishes. Thus it seems that the powers of $(t-t_0)$ in the denominator goes with $\mathcal{O} (3k/2)$ while the powers of $(t-t_0)$ in the numerator goes with $\mathcal{O}(k)$. Intuitively I would say that $m$ diverges to infinity.

Comment: this is almost true. Be careful that the constant term that multiplies $(t-t_0)$ in the numerator might equal zero, in which case it is equivalent to $(t-t_0)^2$ or even a higher-order power and your conclusion is not valid.

Comment: @Oliv You are correct. Even in the case of analytic functions I don't know how to attack this problem. I looked for some theorem which may support this intuitive idea of mine (to look at the powers of $(t-t_0)$), but I couldn't find. Do you have some analysis book or PDF to suggest? However I am much more interested on the smooth case.